# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists() and [avoid duplicate data in csv ]

Tags: php, laravel

> error:=> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()

And how to avoid duplicate data in **.CSV** file type..

```
public function import(Request $request){

     $this -> validate($request, [
       'import_file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xlsx|max:2048',
    ]);

     if($request->hasFile('import_file')){

        $rollno = Student::lists('rollno')->toArray();

        $file = $request->file('import_file') ;

        $fileName =  date('Y-m-d_H-i-s')."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/' ;

        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName); 

        $path=$destinationPath.$fileName;//"uploads/testfile_xlsx.xlsx";

        $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();

        if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                if (in_array($value->rollno, $rollno))

                continue;

                $insert[] = ['name' => $value->name,'rollno' => $value->rollno,'department' => $value->department, 'course' => $value->course,'image_name'=>''];

            }
            if(!empty($insert)){
                DB::table('students')->insert($insert);
                return back()->with('success','Insert Record successfully.');

            }

        }

        else{unlink($path); return back()->with('error','Please Check your file. No Rows'); }

    }

    return back()->with('error','Something is wrong there.');
}
```

Comment: There is simply no method lists() on your model Student. The line `Student::lists('rollno')->toArray();` causes the error. What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: avoid duplicate data in uploaded csv  file...

Comment: Alright, but you can't use lists() with only one parameter. You should try something like `Student::lists('rollno', 'id')` if there is an `id` column.

Comment: You could also use the pluck function, like this: `Student::all()->pluck('rollno');`

Comment: `Student::all()->pluck('rollno'); `its works...really thanks...u r great...

Comment: It's a pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using laravel version `>=5.3` then use [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) method instead of `lists`. Answer is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114249/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builderlists-when-seeding/39148004#39148004).